# how can i cause an animation to run also when the screen is off?

Tags: flutter, animation, stopwatch

i have a stopwatch in my application. this stopwatch build from CirclePercentIndicator package and the precent property is controlled by animation this combination creates the stopwatch.

The problem is as soon as the animation starts running it takes a while and the screen turns off but the animation also stops and the clock that is supposed to continue running stops .

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

When i wrote the code i disposed the controller on dispose function. when i omit it , the problem solve .